# Partial display of text

Tags: utf-8, character-encoding, webfonts, iso-8859-1, cyrillic

Cyrillic text is partially displayed
[this is how looks](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TqElW.png)

html was:
META HTTP-EQUIV="Content-Type" CONTENT="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1

I change in:
META HTTP-EQUIV="Content-Type" CONTENT="text/html; charset=utf-8

Nothing has changed.
In Serbia, Cyrillic fonts with a Latin code layout were used for a long time. I don't know if that's the problem.

Do you know where to start troubleshooting?
This is an old site that once won an award.

change iso to utf, look in css but not saw the problem

Comment: Looks like the embedded page is UTF-8-encoded but displayed as ISO-8859-1 as you suspect.  Without any other code, all I can say is find the correct place to add the UTF-8 metadata.